# Class function is returning None Python

Tags: python, binary-tree, inorder

I am writing a binary tree in Python. I want my in order traversal to return an array of the tree values. It is printing them fine, but the array never makes it back to the variable I'm trying to capture it in and my test fails with None not equal Expected.

```
def inOrder(self, **kwargs):
        root = self.assignRoot(kwargs)
        arr = self.assignArr(kwargs)
        # recurse down or 'visit' node
        if root.left != None:
            self.inOrder(arr=arr, root=root.left)
        arr.append(root.value)
        if len(arr) == self.length:
            print('returning arr', arr)
            return arr
        if root.right != None:
            self.inOrder(arr=arr, root=root.right)
```

My test looks like this:

```
from btree import Btree
from btree import Node
def test_inOrder_traversal():
    bst = setUp()
    print(bst.root.value)
    arr = bst.inOrder()
    print('arr', arr)
    expected = [10, 15, 20, 25, 30]
    assert arr == expected
```

the print statement also shows arr == None so it not returning properly from inOrder()

EDIT:
this solved it.

```
def inOrder(self, **kwargs):
        root = self.assignRoot(kwargs)
        arr = self.assignArr(kwargs)
        # recurse down or 'visit' node
        if root.left != None:
            self.inOrder(arr=arr, root=root.left)
        arr.append(root.value)
        if root.right != None:
            self.inOrder(arr=arr, root=root.right)
        if len(arr) == self.length:
            print('returning arr', arr)
            return arr
```

Comment: the `inOrder` function doesn't return something in all cases, only if the lengths are the same.

Comment: The lengths have to be the same. length is an instance variable tracking how many nodes are in the tree (updated on insertion and removal). I'm using it to indicate the inOrder traversal has completed. The 'returning arr' print statement is also printing with the correct value for arr.

Comment: ok so moving the if statement that checks length to the end of the function makes everything work. i think this has something to do with call stack depth and where the return statement was returning to.